# Why does a program disabled as a service still runs at the system's startup?

Tags: services, tor

I installed Tor (to run it as a node, not simply the browser) on my desktop and laptop. But as I use desktop almost all the time and the connection to the Internet is the same, I run tor only on the desktop, but on the laptop I would like to disable it but not to uninstall Tor.

I disabled it (at least I think so) with the help of the `sysrv-conf` utility. None of the runlevels is checked.

But when I restart the laptop I see Tor as running:

```
$ps aux | grep tor
........ /usr/lib/bin/tor ..........
```

and the log file says that Tor performed some activity:

```
$tail /var/log/tor/log
...... Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
```

Could anyone explain to me, please, what happens? I thought that every program which starts and runs in background, without a user's help is considered a service/daemon and can be disabled. But this notion flies in the face of this situation, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that since Ubuntu 15.04 Ubuntu distros use **systemd** init-service instead of SysVinit or Upstart. So a service must be disabled with this command:

```
sudo systemctl disable SERVICENAME.service
```

If one is confused with all this stuff: *init-service, systemd, SysVinit, Upstart* I can recommend to read Chapter 15 "Starting and Stopping Services" from [the Linux Bible by Chris Negus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118999878)